# Duplication with 2 enumerate in itertools.product causing issues with data python

Tags: python, python-itertools, enumerate

It seems there is something going on with the way the `itertools.product` has been written here I have the below method in class. Which more or less does what I need however there is an issue with the way the data is being created.

```py
    def replace_multiple_npi_lists(self):
        conn = self.establish_connection()

        list_ids = []  # list of unique list ids
        new_npis = []  # list of new npis

        df = pd.read_csv("./uploads/new_file.csv")[["NAME", "NPI_ID"]]
        df = df.dropna()

        if get_npi_lists := self.get_all_account_npi_lists(561939):
            for name in get_npi_lists:
                npi_list = {
                    "id": name["id"],
                    "name": name["name"],
                }

                list_ids.extend(
                    npi_list["id"]
                    for target in df["NAME"].unique()
                    if target == npi_list["name"]
                )

        for target in df["NAME"].unique():
            new_list = df[df["NAME"] == target].reset_index(drop=True)
            new_list = new_list["NPI_ID"].apply(lambda x: str(int(x))).to_list()

            final_list = dict(npis=new_list)
            new_npis.append(final_list)

        try:
            # loop through new_lists and send list to npis
            for (i, npis), (i, id) in itertools.product(
                enumerate(new_npis), enumerate(list_ids)
            ):

                if id == list_ids[i]:

                    r = conn.put(
                        f"https://xxx.xxx.com/RestApi/v1/npi/npi-list/{id}",
                        json=npis,
                    )
                    r.raise_for_status()

                    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
                        print(f"List #{i + 1} has been uploaded")
                        new_list = {"id": id, "npis": npis}
                        print(new_list)
                        time.sleep(5)
                        self.establish_connection()

        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
            print(r.json())
```

Then end point accepts an `id` in the URL and a json body like so:

```json
{
   'npis': [
          122,
          123,
          ...
         ]
}
```

I have formatted the below via print statements so i can see if the correct numbers are being passed to the right ids.

The method works, it does what I want it to do in terms of functionality but it doesn't create the dicts the way i need for them to be sent.

- `list_ids`: is a list of unique IDS
- `new_npis`: is a list of dicts that hold NPI numbers

##### list_ids

```py
[4151, 8785, 8786]
```

##### new_npis

```py
[{'npis': ['3099994294', '1430739187', '5968165218']}, {'npis': ['3559958528', '2502671659', '7646439044']}, {'npis': ['8065327496', '3487201540', '4693760324']}]
```

I believe my issue lies with how I have written the loop in the try clause, the output from the loop consists of the following:

```sh
List #1 has been uploaded
{'id': 4151, 'npis': {'npis': ['3099994294', '1430739187', '5968165218']}}
List #2 has been uploaded
{'id': 8785, 'npis': {'npis': ['3099994294', '1430739187', '5968165218']}}
List #3 has been uploaded
{'id': 8786, 'npis': {'npis': ['3099994294', '1430739187', '5968165218']}}
List #1 has been uploaded
{'id': 4151, 'npis': {'npis': ['3559958528', '2502671659', '7646439044']}}
List #2 has been uploaded
{'id': 8785, 'npis': {'npis': ['3559958528', '2502671659', '7646439044']}}
List #3 has been uploaded
{'id': 8786, 'npis': {'npis': ['3559958528', '2502671659', '7646439044']}}
List #1 has been uploaded
{'id': 4151, 'npis': {'npis': ['8065327496', '3487201540', '4693760324']}}
List #2 has been uploaded
{'id': 8785, 'npis': {'npis': ['8065327496', '3487201540', '4693760324']}}
List #3 has been uploaded
{'id': 8786, 'npis': {'npis': ['8065327496', '3487201540', '4693760324']}}
```

So currently it does want I want to a certain degree, how ever it seems to be adding the first dict from `new_npis` to the all `id`s in `list_ids` and then looping over them again to add the second dict from `new_npis` and so on.

The desired end result is to be the following:

```sh
{'id': 4151, 'npis': {'npis': ['3099994294', '1430739187','5968165218']}}

{'id': 8785, 'npis': {'npis': ['3559958528', '2502671659', '7646439044']}}

{'id': 8786, 'npis': {'npis': ['8065327496', '3487201540', '4693760324']}}
```

excuse the formatting here of the dicts it's the only way I could get them to print

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by doing the following:

```py
for i, npis in enumerate(new_npis):

                r = conn.put(
                    f"https://xxx.xxx.com/RestApi/v1/npi/npi-list/{list_ids[i]}",
                    json=npis,
                )
                r.raise_for_status()
```